# Can I use Fluent UI for creating websites not related to any Microsoft Apps?

Tags: office-ui-fabric

Can I use Fluent UI for creating websites not related to any Microsoft Apps? I read the LICENSE file and even though it says MIT license, the following line related to Fabric assets is somewhat confusing because it says that we can use Fabric assets only for Microsoft related apps. So can't I use Fluent UI and with the icons and font in normal website like I use Bootstrap or Material Design?

"Note: Usage of the fonts and icons referenced in Fluent UI React is subject to the terms listed at https://aka.ms/fluentui-assets-license "

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55389251/can-i-use-office-ui-fabric-react-in-a-non-microsoft-internal-application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can use it now like any other Bootstrap or Material design

add this module to 
 `<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@fluentui/web-components"></script>`

For any further references about Fluent UI Web Components visit: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fluent-ui/web-components/getting-started/quick-start)

But these are limited but fast and neat.