# Using UI Fabric Icons - in application that is Azure/MS services dependent, but it is a standalone web application

Tags: office-ui-fabric, fluent-ui, fluentui-react, office-ui-fabric-react

It is not clear to me if I can use fabricUI icons & Segoe UI font in my project

According to [this license](https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/assets/microsoft_fabric_assets_license_agreement_nov_2019.pdf) which can be found in [the project repository](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/blob/master/LICENSE)

I have found [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55389251/can-i-use-office-ui-fabric-react-in-a-non-microsoft-internal-application) which is linking to [this issue in the Fluent Repo](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/issues/3312#issuecomment-342576387)

> Fabric's assets (fonts, icons, and product logos) are part of Microsoft's brand, and can only be used in apps & services--including commercial ones--that connect with Microsoft products. These include Add-ins for Office, web parts for SharePoint, and other extensions for Microsoft products. This applies to usage of the assets in application code itself as well as any designs produced by the toolkit.

I am building a commercial application that can be used as an Excel add-in and have a separate URL where can be used as a standalone web app. Can I use Fabric Icons and SegoeUI font in both places?

My application is 100% MS services dependent (MS Auth, multiple azure services) and I would like to have the same design.